# Find the equation of the orthogonal family

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

1. If $\;\; \displaystyle {dy\over dt} = 2y(12-3y),\;$ and $y(0)=1$, what is the maximum value?
2. Find the equation for the orthogonal family $y= Ce^{5x}.$

Comment: If you have two different questions on the same general topic, it's best to post *one* of them, wait for answers, think about the answers, see whether they help you do the other question: if they don't help, *then* post the other question.

Answer (score 2):

1) $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dt} = 2y (12-3y) \\
\displaystyle \int \frac{dy}{y(4-y)} = 6\int dt \\
\displaystyle \frac 14 \int \left [
\frac 1y + \frac 1{4-y}
\right] = 6 \int dt \\
\displaystyle \ln y + \ln (4-y) = 24t + C \\
\displaystyle y (4-y) = D e^{24t}$

It's implicit equation for $y$. You need to find $D$ by substituting $y(0) = 1$, so $D = 1$ and $y(4-y) = e^{24t}$. This equation doesn't define a function, so you cannot use concepts applicable for functions to $y$, such as extrema. This equation has two branches, and each of them is a function.
[image: Blue and Red]

2) $\displaystyle y = f(x) = C e^{5x} \\
\frac {df}{dx} = 5C e^{5x}$

Let's use $g(x)$ for orthogonal family, so

$\displaystyle \frac{df}{dx} \frac{dg}{dx} = -1 \\
\displaystyle \frac {dg}{dx} = -\frac 1{5C} e^{-5x} \\
\displaystyle g(x) = \frac 1{25C} e^{-5x}$